# Java Socket unable to communicate with AWS ServerSocket

Tags: java, sockets, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a two java programs, one a server and one a client that have no problems communicating over a LAN, but they seem unable to interact over internet.

The server program's socket line is

```
ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(serverPort,backLog,InetAddress.getByName(serverIp));
```

and the client's line is

```
Socket s = new Socket(serverAddress,serverPort);
```

I get no errors on the server side, but the client side socket never fails to give me

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

after a few seconds.

The netstat -a command when run on the server gives me

```
TCP   172.31.26.69:2674    WIN-CHU42MQF3R4:0    LISTENING
```

which I believe means the ServerSocket is listening to any internet communications directed at port 2674.  Again, this program works perfectly when run on my LAN, it just cannot communicate over the internet.

I've confirmed no other programs on both computers are using port 2674, and I've allowed all forms and ports of communication on the AWS server as well as opening port 2674 on my own firewall.  But I cannot think of anything else that might be causing the issue.  Is there anything that might interfere?

Comment: Can you ping the AWS server from the client? Another dummy question just to clear the field....if you are on Windows are you sure to have enabled the JVM to "connect to the network"? I've worked on a desktop client/server app and I remember weird thing on the first run on Windows boxes.

Comment: Yes, I tried to ping both computers from the other and that was successful.  I copied the JRE folder from my computer to the AWS server, so they should have the same settings, but is there a way to check that the JVM can connect to network?